# Settings for point cloud in OpenDroneMap

Tags: opendronemap

I'm bit confused. When I process an image set in OpenDroneMap orthophoto creation works really good, also mesh creation (including textures). The only problem that I have is with point cloud. Always has missing data (see images below), I have been testing different parameter settings in `settings.yaml` file with no succeed.

I use LAS file to create DSM and DEM and this issue affects directly the final result. Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Orthophoto:

[image]

Point cloud (`.las` or `.ply` file)

[image]

Comment: What is it like near the middle of your swath? As I understand it drone mapping uses raster correlation to create a point cloud not a separate LiDAR sensor - if you don't have two or more images you can't correlate, though it does look like the edge of a swath with terrain/vegetation hiding the ground behind it.

Comment: In road I have an overlapping above 60% between images (3 in this case). Is a plain place, also. In trees I don't see problems like this